# Application crashes when passing array of animations

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

I thought it would be a brilliant idea to pass an array of animations to an internal function that runs all animations one after each other, so I wouldn't need to nest animations within each other and each others' completionBlock. So I wrote a little method to test this out and, guess what, it crashes like hell. But I don't understand why. This is my method:

```
+(void) internalAnimateWithArrayOfAnimationBlocks:(NSArray*) animationBlocks withIndex:(NSUInteger) index withCompletionAnimation:(void (^)(BOOL finished)) completionBlock { 
  __block NSArray* newAnims = animationBlocks;
  __block NSUInteger theIndex = index;
  if (index < [newAnims count] - 1) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
      void (^animBlock) (void) = [newAnims objectAtIndex:theIndex];
      animBlock();
      theIndex++;
      [RMAnimater internalAnimateWithArrayOfAnimationBlocks:newAnims withIndex:theIndex withCompletionAnimation:completionBlock];
    }];
  }
  else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
      void (^animBlock) (void) = [newAnims objectAtIndex:theIndex];
      animBlock();
      theIndex++;
    } completion:completionBlock];
  }
}

+(void) animateWithArrayOfAnimationBlocks:(NSArray*) animationBlocks withCompletionAnimation:(void (^)(BOOL finished)) completionBlock { 
  [RMAnimater internalAnimateWithArrayOfAnimationBlocks:animationBlocks withIndex:0 withCompletionAnimation:completionBlock];
}
```

I pass this animations like this:

```
NSMutableArray* animations = [NSMutableArray array];
[animations addObject:^{
  CGRect frame = theTile.textField.frame;
  frame.origin.x -= 10;
  theTile.textField.frame = frame;
}];
```

When I debug it, it kindly goes through all my animations, calls the final animation with its completion block and then crashes deadly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Crashes deadly" is not very specific.  What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, call `-addObject:` of `NSMutableArray` will retain but not copy the added object. When you declare a block, it's in stack, which will be destroy in the end of the scope. To make it into heap, you must `Block_copy` or send `copy` message to the block. So to fix your problem, you must:

```
NSMutableArray* animations = [NSMutableArray array];
void (^animBlock)(void) = Block_copy(^{
  CGRect frame = theTile.textField.frame;
  frame.origin.x -= 10;
  theTile.textField.frame = frame;
});
[animations addObject:animBlock];
Block_release(animBlock);
```